# SUM across other worksheets (without hardcoding their names)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I've got a spreadsheet for my organisation's management accounts. Each project has a worksheet, setting out income and expenditure by financial year. This is aggregated together in a few sheets including a Profit & Loss.

I want to devise a formula that will add up a particular cell from all the project worksheets, but without hardcoding the worksheet names in the formula. That's because I add and remove projects, and don't want the formula to break.

Is there something equivalent to "add up this cell in all the worksheets with a name beginning with R-"?

Alternatively, can I create a list from a row that contains all the project names, and then use an `ARRAYFORMULA` to cycle through them finding the appropriate value and summing them all?

Here's some background on the spreadsheet...

The project worksheets look like this:

```
Accounting code | 2018-19 | 2019-20 | 2020-21
----------------------------------------------
Income general  | £20,000 | £25,000 | £15,000
```

The P&L columns for that project like this:

```
Accounting code | Project name
                | Budget for year | Budget to date | Actual to date
-------------------------------------------------
Income general  | £20,000         | £16,000        | £15,463
```

The 'budget for year' figure is pulled out as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A9,INDIRECT("'"&N$4&"'!$A5:$Z100"),MATCH(v_CurYr,INDIRECT("'"&N$4&"'!$A4:$E4")),FALSE),0)
```

Where $A9 is that row's accounting code, N$4 references the project name, and v_CurYr is a cell giving the current year (2018-19).

For the `ARRAYFORMULA`, we could use the row that has the headers for the project names, but the names appear in every 4th column - the others in between being blanks.

Comment: pls, share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

> the names appear in every 4th column

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:1, MOD(COLUMN(A1:1), 4)=0))
```

> all the worksheets with a name beginning with `R-`

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:1, MOD(COLUMN(A1:1), 4)=0)), "where Col1 contains 'R-'", 0)
```

[image]

> can I create a list from a row that contains all the project names, and then cycle through them finding the appropriate value and summing them all?

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(A5&"!A9"))+
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(A6&"!A9"))+
 IFERROR(INDIRECT(A7&"!A9"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. The QUERY/TRANSPOSE bits pull out the list of project names. But I meant something different by the next step.

Rather than hardcoding the list of projects, as you have done, I want to dynamically use the list produced by the QUERY.

If I were coding this in appscript it would be a loop, to cycle through the project names and for each used INDEX and MATCH to find the value, and add it to the running total. I don't know if that's possible in a gsheets formula?

Comment: I would call it semi-hardcoding coz as you can see A7 is empty eg. if it becomes dynamically not empty then it will properly sum up. if not, it stays ignored. yeah, with a script it could be possible.